# How to detect Carriage return in a string

Tags: string, c#-4.0

Here is the problem. I am working on a project in WPF and C# with 4.0 .net platform. I have a string which i got from a textbox with Accepts return = "true". The string is as follows

```
string P = @"Copyright 1995-2010 BYTES.
            All rights Reserved.
            Formerly "TheScripts.com" from 2005-2008";
```

Now i want to detect when the  carriage return character is encountered. So that i can cut the string short to just "Copyright 1995-2010 BYTES." and remove all the characters after carriage return is encountered.

I tried doing this

```
string ip = datarow[0].ToString();
string trimed= ip.TrimEnd(new char[] {'\r','\n'});
profileFNcb.Items.Add(trimed);
```

NOT WORKING PLEASE HELP GUYS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) with [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) in order to split the string on line breaks:

```
myString.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, 
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This results in a string array containing each line.

To get the first line, assuming the returned `string[]` is in a `lines` variable:

```
string firstLine = lines[0]; // firstLine = "Copyright 1995-2010 BYTES."
```

The reasons your solution is not working - the `TrimEnd` only removes the characters from the *end* of the string, not the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Oh: I misread your question - this should help:

```
string onlyCopyright = P.Substring(0, P.IndexOf("\n"));
```

Or even better:

```
string onlyCopyright = P.Substring(0, P.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

`Trim` only removes whitespace at the beginning and the end of a string. You want to replace:

```
string noNewLine = ip.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... awesome that did it. Thank you again Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

TrimEnd removes the trailing characters, it does not "end" the string at the first instance of those characters. What you need to do is search for the first instance of '\r' or '\n' and keep the substring of the characters before that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string P = @"Copyright 1995-2010 BYTES.
        All rights Reserved.
        Formerly ""TheScripts.com"" from 2005-2008";

string firstLine = P.Split(
                       new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine },
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
```