# Removing dangling CR in a file using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a scenario where in I have a dangling **CR**(Carriage Return) in my file. But each line is delimited by **CRLF**.

For example I have a following line in the file say input.txt:

> Stackoverflow is a lovely site to use **CR** for any novice user
>   **CRLF**

If I use the method ReadAllLines in my code. I get 2 distinct strings.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(input.txt)

lines[0] = "Stackoverflow is a lovely site to use "

lines[1] = "for any novice user "
```

Now I have to eliminate only the **CR** in the above line and preserve the **CRLF**

So that I can get;

```
lines[0] = "Stackoverflow is a lovely site to use for any novice user "
```

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: You should show some attempt if you hope to get some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually normalize line endings like this:

```
str.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "\r\n")
```

Variations of this are possible.

Comment: Thanks Usr... It worked perfectly... And sorry for a very late reply.... :)

Comment: This is what I did finally. 
String fileTxt = File.ReadToEnd("C:\input.txt");
String cleanedUpFile = fileTxt.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","\r\n");
File.WriteAllText("C:\output.txt",cleanedUpFile);

Comment: The technique commented above posted a vulnerable threat. While reading multiple large files I used to get SystemOutOfMemory exceptions. My colleague Muniraju helped me solve this problem use extension Methods. Write a extension method for ReadLines.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to [How to detect Carriage return in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720430/how-to-detect-carriage-return-in-a-string), try this :

```
string noCR = line.Replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: Thanks auburg. This will not work for multiple line file. But your solution holds good for a single line file. Probably I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the String.Replace.

So:

```
string test = lines[0].Replace("CR", "");
```

or do that with the character "\n".

I think it should work

Comment: Thanks for the ans guys. Your solution will give unexpected results. But my file will end up only with "\r" and no "\n". This might create problems further in the pipeline. Your suggestion will work for single line. But not for multiple lines text. May be I had to be more specific. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the whole file and splitting the lines yourself

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("my file");
string[] lines = test.Split('\r', '\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will give you an array of strings with each element a line. No lines will contain or end with `CRLF` or `CR`, or `LF`.

Now you want to stich them back together. Try this.

```
string textWithoutLineEndings = string.Join(" ", lines);
```

Comment: Thanks for editing Gusdor.